# RSYNC over SSH requesting password

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, rsync, cron

I looked at numerous question but don't seem to find quite what I'm looking for.

I've created a script in which I'm trying to run rsync over ssh, this will eventually be put into a cron job. The variables are all defined and the important part of the script reads:

`$RSYNC -az --stats -e "$SSH -i $KEY" $RUSER@RHOST:$RPATH $LPATH`

KEY points to my private key, with the public copied to RHOST and added to authorized users.

Currently the permissions on RPATH are 775, when I try to run the script I'm prompted for RHOSTs password, which going into a cron job isn't very useful.

If I however I change the permissions on RPATH to 755, the script runs without prompting for a password. Unfortunately I can't make this change permanently.

So I have a three part question; 
First is this rsync or ssh causing me trouble? 
Second why does this behave this way? It doesn't make sense to me that allowing group write access to the directory should make the difference in being prompted for a password. 
Third and finally I'm looking for ideas on a way to resolve this. RUSER has sudo privileges. (I rather not embed the password in the command line.)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's what I ended up doing, @MariusMatutiae got me headed in the right direction!

Based on some other recommendations I found I'm running running rsync as sudo over ssh. I created a new user *BKUPuser* on remotehost and added this user to the RHOST group that owns the files I'm trying to backup.

In sudoers I added two lines: 
`BKUPuser ALL= NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync` this stopped the error: "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified" ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92123/rsync-all-files-of-remote-machine-over-ssh-without-root-user ) I understand this has some security vulnerabilities but neither machine is visible to the outside world.

The second addition: 
`Defaults:user !requiretty` this stopped error: "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo"

Then the command ended up being: 
`$RSYNC -e "$SSH -i $KEY -t -l BKUPuser" --rsync-path='sudo rsync'-az --stats BKUPuser@RHOST:$RPATH $LPATH`

The only problem I still have is getting an error "Psuedo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal." As rsync is backing up the files it's only an annoyance at this point. I tried using -t -t as suggested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114990/pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-terminal but no luck.

Comment: Thank you for the posting. I came to the same issue and this post helped me to add two time the user name. First for ssh, second as rsync user. To hide the last annoyance, I added ` -q ` to the ssh part of the command. It does not fix it of course, just hides the complaint.

Comment: Apparently it can be a little more secure by permitting only the exact command needed to sync the files in the sudoers. `BKUPuser ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync --server --sender -vlogDtpre.iLsf . /path/to/sync/down` Where $RPATH is the "/path/to/sync/down"

Comment: Here is a blog [describing how to get out the exact command](https://chrisdown.name/2013/11/04/securely-automating-rsync-to-archive-sensitive-files.html) that is run on the RHOST.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual (*man rsync*), you are not using the correct *-l* option:

> If you need to specify a different remote-shell user, keep in mind that the user@ prefix in front of the  host  is  specifying
>          the  rsync-user  value  (for  a  module that requires user-based authentication).  This means that you must give the â-l userâ
>          option to ssh when specifying the remote-shell, as in this example that uses the short version of the --rsh option:

```
       rsync -av -e "ssh -l ssh-user" rsync-user@host::module /dest

   The "ssh-user" will be used at the ssh level; the "rsync-user" will be used to log-in to the "module".
```

Comment: changing the line to `$RSYNC -az --stats -e "$SSH -l $KEY" $RUSER@RHOST:$RPATH $LPATH` results in the same behavior.

Comment: I,... understand, in fact it should be ssh -l ssh-user -i key

Comment: As I only have the sigle user I tried `$RSYNC -az --stats -e "$SSH -l $RUSER $KEY" $RUSER@RHOST:$RPATH $LPATH` - no change. Also on the man page this appears to be talking about use with a daemon on the remote machine which is not what I'm doing.